# Missing return Statement, Recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, return

I keep getting the error

> Palindrome.java:36: error: missing return statement    }    ^ 1 error

when i try to compile, for the lab I have to have a recursive method which returns true if the input string is a palindrome ignoring non letter characters. So what is the problem and how do i go about fixing it.

```
package lab07;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      while ( input.hasNext()){
        String line =  normalise(input.next());
      System.out.println(isPalindrome(line));
      }
}
   public static String normalise(String line){
    String s = "";
    char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        if ( Character.isLetter(chars[i]))
        s += Character.toLowerCase(chars[i]);
}
    return s;
   }
   public static boolean isPalindrome(String line){
    if ( line.length() > 1 ){
        if (line.charAt(0) == line.charAt(line.length()-1)){
            isPalindrome(line.substring(1, line.length()-1));
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    else
        return true;
   }
```

Comment: Having two returns in a method, it's a bad programming style. Please advoid that.

Comment: Which line is line 36?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `return` statement inside the inner `if` condition

```
   public static boolean isPalindrome(String line){
    if ( line.length() > 1 ){
        if (line.charAt(0) == line.charAt(line.length()-1)){
            isPalindrome(line.substring(1, line.length()-1));
               // MISSING RETURN HERE
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    else
        return true;
   }
```

There needs to be a `return` for *every possible* condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result of the recursive case:

```
 public static boolean isPalindrome(String line){
    if ( line.length() > 1 ){
        if (line.charAt(0) == line.charAt(line.length()-1)){
            return isPalindrome(line.substring(1, line.length()-1));

        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (line.charAt(0) == line.charAt(line.length()-1)){
            isPalindrome(line.substring(1, line.length()-1));
    //specify return here    
        }


Here  no return;
```

You specified return type boolean.So in all possible cases you need to provide the return type.