# Why is this recursive function breaking?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to create a function that will take the address of a a pointer and decrement the value (that it is pointing to) to one. Once it is equal to one, it will return 1. When I do this, it prints out:

```
10 
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
32767
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int downToOne(int * & x)
{
  if(*x == 1)
    return 1;

  else
  {
    (*x)--;
    cout<<*x<<endl;
    downToOne(x);   
  }

}

int main() 
{

  int *Ptr = new int(10);
  cout<<*Ptr<<endl;

  cout<<downToOne(Ptr)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Why is it printing out the `32767`?

Comment: Why do you have `int * & x` instead of simply `int *x`?

Comment: Secondly, you didn't return a value in `downToOne()`'s `else` branch.

Comment: Why are you allocating an `int`, and never calling `delete` on it? You know, you could just pass a pointer to a stack-allocated number in there. Using recursion for this sort of thing is also super inefficient and will likely overflow for non-trivial values.

Comment: Why not use the debugger, and use a starting point of `2` instead of `10`?  Then you can easily step through the code and seeing what is happening at the `1` case.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3218c95f760e275)

Comment: @MooseInTheSack Turn on more compiler warnings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing return Statement, Recursive method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537477/missing-return-statement-recursive-method)

Comment: I see no recursive methods

Answer (score 4):

Because that is the (undefined) return value for the first call to downToOne.  The main routine is printing the value returned by the first call to downToOne.  The recursive calls happen within downToOne, and when you flow through that path, downToOne does not return a value.  If you put a "return 9999;" right after recursive call in downToOne, you will see that it prints 9999.  Since there is no explicit return there, you're probably getting whatever value happens to be in the location on the stack for the function return.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is subject to undefined behavior since the function `downToOne` does not have a `return` statement in the `else` branch.

Simplify it to:

```
int downToOne(int* x) // You don't need a reference to the pointer.
{
   if(*x == 1)
      return 1;

   (*x)--;
   cout<<*x<<endl;
   return downToOne(x);   
}
```

The function will cause infinite recursion if `*x` is less than 1. To prevent that problem, it will be better to use:

```
int downToOne(int* x)
{
   if(*x <= 1)  // Prevents infinite recursion
      return 1;

   (*x)--;
   cout<<*x<<endl;
   return downToOne(x);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to round things out, as my comment stated, if you started out using `2` instead of `10`, the problem should have been obvious, or at the very least, very simple to debug and diagnose.

In general, if there is an issue with recursion, start with the simplest case.  Don't try and stress test your recursive function if the simplest cases do not work.

Let's see what happens if the input is changed to `2` instead of `10`:

```
int downToOne(int * & x)
{
  if(*x == 1)  // first time, *x is 2, so the return is not executed.
    return 1;  // second time we return 1.

  else
  {
    (*x)--;   // *x now becomes 1
    cout<<*x<<endl;  // a "1" is printed
    downToOne(x);    // we call again
  }
}
```

Let's see your `main` function:

```
int main() 
{
  int *Ptr = new int(2);
  cout << *Ptr << endl;  // prints a "2"
  cout << downToOne(Ptr) << endl;  // prints a "1" inside of the function, and prints the return value, which is undefined
  return 0;
}
```

So even if you were not aware of undefined behavior, there is no way your `main` function could have printed just 2 numbers.  There would have been 3 numbers printed.

1. The initial "2" is printed
2. The "1" is printed from inside `downToOne`
3. The return value of `downToOne` gets printed in `main`.

Given that scenario, then there are two issue.  The first is the undefined value (which others have answered), and the second being that you're printing too many times.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in the `else` branch it does not return anything, but you are using the return value of that branch for your last cout statement. So it outputs a random value. If you add a return statement into the else branch, whatever you returned from there will be output instead of 32767 in the current output.

Answer (score -1):

The output it should and does generate is

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
1

When *x is 2 it goes to the else block, decrements *x by 1, then prints it. Then the first call on the stack(from main()) print another 1.

Are you sure you are running the same code?

Answer (score -3):

This way it works fine....

```
{
    int* ptr = new int(10);
    cout << "ptr = " << *ptr << "\n\n";

    int downToOne(int*); //THIS is the correct form

    cout << downToOne(ptr) << "\n";

    return 0;
}


int downToOne(int* x)
{
    if(*x == 1)
        return 1;

    else
    {
        cout << *x << endl;
        (*x)--;
        downToOne(x);
    }
}
```

`ptr = 10`

`10`
`9`
`8`
`7`
`6`
`5`
`4`
`3`
`2`
`1`
`Press <RETURN> to close this window...`

---

### EDIT 2015-11-10_15:15

There you go, this version works as well and has a `return` expression.

```
int downToOne(int* x)
{
//    if(*x == 1) //comment out
//        return 1; //comment out
//    else //comment out
//    { //comment out

    if (*x != 1) //add this
    { //add this
        cout<<*x<<endl;
        (*x)--;
        downToOne(x);
    } //add this

//    } //comment out

    return *x; //add this
}
```

Comment: Still not returning anything if `*x` is not 1.

Comment: Strange, the output I've posted is just a copy/paste of what appears on my screen. I've just re-run it to be sure I didnt mistype anything, and it works just fine.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. It *might* seem to work from time to time, but it's wrong. Compile with more warnings.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. It works and gives me no warning....none relevant, just one that warns me because you forgot to put a final `return` expression at the end of the `downToOne` function definition.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. `downToOne()` returns something undefined when `*x != 1`.

Comment: On my IDE it works perfectly....probably because my IDE doesnt return values when there's no `return` expressions.

Comment: If the function has been declared to return `int` there's no way to ‘not return a value’. Something has to be returned. In this case something undefined.

Comment: Again, my IDE doesnt return values where there's no `return` expressions, but still, you just have to put an `if` scope around the `downToOne` recursion and then add a `return 0;` at the end of the function. If the return value is `0`, then.....I'm sure you can come up with something smart to handle this case.

Comment: ‘*my IDE doesnt return values where there's no `return` expressions*’ That's simply not possible. The result of the first call to `downToOne()` is even printed to `cout` in this case. It *happens to be* `1`, as seen in the output, but that's just luck. Not returning anything from a non-void function is bad. *Using* that value is *really* bad. *Relying on* undefined behaviour is *horrible*!

Comment: I've modified the `downToOne` function to return the right value. It works. Enjoy!

Comment: @MooseInTheSack Now it works, and has a proper `return` expression in the `downToOne` function.